# UITableView section details drawing wrong on scroll

Tags: iphone, uitableview, scroll

I have a `UITableView`, and I am showng data based on `indexPath.section`, however, when I scroll my table view very quickly, its data keep overlapping. How to fix this?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }
    switch(indexPath.section)
    {
    // case 0 to 10;
    //values change if I scroll my table 
}
```

}

Comment: "shake my tableview very fast"? What?

Comment: i mean if i scroll my table very fast then data shuffles

Answer (score 6):

I think you are allocating some labels inside the cellForRowAtIndex delegate method. Thats why you got this problem. You can solve this in 2 ways:

- Alloc the labels outside the delegate
  method. set tags for your labels and
  use it inside the cellForRowAtIndex
  by refering the tags.
- use custom cell view controller.

Comment: I'm using custom cells, but still have the same problem. The last label in the cell is set to be multiline. If I scroll slowly everything is ok, if I scroll fast in some cells this label looks like someone randomly put several "newlines", so it overlaps the next cell. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

i fixed the issues

here is the solution if any one need

```
NSString *CellIdentifier=nil ;


    NSMutableArray *Array=  [[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"One",@"Two", @"Three",@"Ad",@"Ae",@"Ah",@"Aj" ,nil]autorelease];



    CellIdentifier = [Array objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];




    ///302-1021-9244-4658-1994-3384 

    UITableViewCell *  cell = [tabelView     dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Thanks

Comment: Had the same problem as you and thought this might prevent it, but instead of trying it I googled and found this :)